# Make certain local variables available to LLVM pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I have the following situation.

I need to insert certain CallInst in my code.

The prototype of my function is

```
void __llvmFooBar(int data, int loc);
```

The parameter loc is generated by the pass. I don't need any external data to generate that.

But, the parameter data is basically calculated by using some variable declared inside my C-code.

```
//test.c
int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    happyEnding(k);
}

void happyEnding(int k)
{
    int __data = seed(time()) + k%2;
    //callInst to be inserted here, it should be
    //__llvmFooBar(__data, 23);
    myAlgorithim();
}
//pass.cpp
......
std::vector<Value *> args(2);
args[0] = ??? //need help here
args[1] = ConstantInt::get(IntegerTy, getLoc());
m_builder->CreateCall(hook, args);
```

In generic sense, how to make all variable with specific naming convention(like starts with __) make available to llvm pass ?

Comment: Have you tried reading Debug Information of an instruction? So for example we have a ICmp Instruction. We can cycle through the user operands, and read the debug value of each operand. The debug value also contains the name of each local variable in use. Once you have the name, you can simply use string compare functions to match names for your specific patterns.